# Вывод данных из массива JSON в pug/jade

Tags: json, pug

В `gulp` есть задача для `pug`

```
gulp.task("html", function() {
  return gulp.src("src/pages/*.pug")
    .pipe(plumber())
    .pipe(pug({
      locals : {
    socials: JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('src/modules/socials/socials.json', 'utf8')),
      }
     }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest("dist"))
});
```

В файле `json` создаю массив с данными

```
{
  "socialsData":
  [
    {
      "title" : "Вконтакте",
    },
    {
      "title" : "Фейсбук",
    }
  ]
}
```

Вывожу `json` массив в файле `pug`

```
ul.socials
  each link, title in socials.socialsData
    li.socials__item= socialsData['title']
```

И получаю в ответ ошибку `Cannot read property 'title' of undefined`. Не понимаю как выводить элементы массива `json` конкретно в `pug`

Comment: socialsData - массив, а раз так, разве у него будет свойство 'title'? socialsData[0]['title] - вот это было бы правильнее, но дело вроде как не в этом.

Comment: Почему, вы, в итерации получаете link, title, но в теле итерации вдруг socialsData['title']? Вообще link - это индекс, title - это элемент массива socialsData, тогда должно быть так: li.socials__item = socialsData[link]['title'].

Comment: @SonicMyst просто с json я должен был получать три параметра: link, prefix, и title. Но для упрощения примера, решил оставить только один параметр, и не обратил внимания на этот участок кода.Но даже как описали Вы, не выводится `Cannot read property '#<Object>' of undefined`

Comment: к сожалению мне это не проверить, поэтому и говорил настолько, насколько представлял и помнил это всё.